# A JMS for Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, jms

I'm working in a Tomcat 6 java web application and I have some requirements that needs to be resolved with a JMS (message queue), but need some orientation to accomplish it.

I know that Glassfish or JBoss implements his JMS Queue, but the company doesn't want to install those.

Are there any opensource alternative to a JMS implementation that could be deployed in tomcat 6?

I researched [this](http://openjms.sourceforge.net/), but after reviewing the page it's looks like a closed project. Can anyone suggest another course?

Comment: you can try [rabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Comment: Spring 3 is a very good option IMO. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-connections

Comment: AFAIK Spring only supports client side support for JMS. You still need a JMS server to connect to. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Correct.  Take that back.  I would re-consider JBoss.

Answer (score 6):

Did you check ActiveMQ integration with Tomcat

[Tutorial](http://rocksolutions.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/configure-apache-activemq-with-tomcat-6/)

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely consider ActiveMQ.

It is very widely used and has a very active user community.

It has lots of advanced features and even supports Enterprise Integration Patterns.

And finally it integrates well into a Spring based application.

[Active MQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

In general, most JMS queue implementations will be standalone apps.  However, you can still deploy your app in Tomcat, and either code directly to the JMS api, or using something like spring-jms or spring-integration to make it easier for yourself.

As people have said, ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ are two very good options for JMS.